# SQL Replace with changing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I need to be able to replace a value in a field for e.g. a I.P - but this I.P will change.

I have tried to use the CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING

```
    case when cr.DateOfCall between convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) and convert(varchar, getdate() +1, 112) then 
            '\\10.10.111.5\Recordings\***\' + 
            substring(***, charindex('\201', ***) + 1, 100)
```

How will I do it so it will replace it with text

Example:

I have the I.P [http://10.10.111.5...] or [http://11.11.222.6...] but I will need this to say - "...//EXAMPLE..."

Comment: You need the value `http://10.10.111.5/xyz/as.c` as `http://EXAMPLE/xyz/as.c`?

Comment: Question not clear. BTW, why are you converting date as varchar here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
declare @tbl as table(Col nvarchar(max))
insert into @tbl values ('http://10.10.111.5/xyz/as.c')
insert into @tbl values ('http://11.11.222.6/asdf/hhl/as.c')

select Stuff(Col, charindex('//', Col, 0)+2, charindex('/', replace(Col, '//', ''), 0)-charindex('//', Col, 0), 'EXAMPLE')
From @tbl
```